# WebMethod not working when deployed

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-autocomplete, webmethod

I have a jQuery UI Autocomplete widget which is populated with a list of objects via a call to a WebMethod.

I'm using C#, .NET 4.0.

This *'works on my machine'* (insert snorts of derision here), but when deployed to the server the autocomplete is not populating due to the WebMethod failing.  I can see the following error in the Console window of IE DevTools:

```
Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'SearchEmployees' failed with the following error: -- There was an error processing the request.
```

Here's is the error in the response to the POST to the WebMethod from Firebug:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

I have a ScriptManager on my page with EnablePageMethods="true"

My method is public and has the `[ScriptMethod()]` and `[WebMethod]` attributes.

Checked the permissions on the database which is called in the WebMethod (kind of a moot point as it's not even getting to the DB call yet).

Checked that I have `using System.Web.Services;` and `using System.Web.Script.Services;`

Checked the target framework for the given AppPool in IIS.

My javascript/jQuery:

```
PageMethods.SearchEmployees(function (results) {
    $("#txtMessageFor").autocomplete({
        source: results,
        delay: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#hfEmployeeEmail').val(ui.item.Email);
        }
    });
});
```

My WebMethod in the CodeBehind:

```
[ScriptMethod()]
[WebMethod]
public static List<Employee> SearchEmployees()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Email FROM TableName";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                List<Employee> contacts = new List<Employee>();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        Employee employee = new Employee();
                        employee.label = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                        employee.value = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                        employee.Name = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                        employee.Email = sdr["Email"].ToString();
                        contacts.Add(employee);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                return contacts;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FakeDBName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

So, can anybody help with why the WebMethod would not be working when deployed?

Comment: May you checked it, but since you are throwing the exception at the end, it is possible that your connection string is not valid in the deployment enviroment and it throws an exception during a select. I think it would be a good idea instead of throwing the exception, loging it somewhere. I think then you could see a more detailed problem here.

Comment: @AndrásOttó  From what I can tell, it's not even getting to the connection string.  I can remove the database completely and I still get the same error which indicates that something is going wrong earlier than that.

Comment: Just for a try I can say you can switch off the custom error mode, may then you can see a more detailed exception. Try to apply the <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors> in the webconfig, which should get you the normal ASP.NET error page, and if I'm right, if the webmethod throwing the exception, you can see more then. (Of course if you have the possibility to try it) But unfortunatly without it your page won't show any detailed exception in any case if you throw something in the catch.

Comment: Or you can try comment the throw Exception out to see what is happening then.

Comment: @AndrásOttó.  Nope.  Nothing at all with custom error off and the throw commented out.  No on-page errors.  It doesn't crash, it just doesn't populate the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Either use fiddler or Firebug in Firefox to check the status of the request that is sent to the webservice, these both tools can give you a better idea. I would suggest first try using firebug as for fidler you will have to do the installation.

One more suggestion that I will like to give you is instead of returning `List<Employee>` you must return something like:

```
public class ReturnEmployee
{
    public List<Employee> Employees {get; set;}

    public string ErrorMessage {get; set;}
}
```

This approach helps a lot in issues identification.

Comment: Here's the response to the POST to the WebMethod: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Checking out the DB config now.

Comment: if you are accessing your SQL Server using instance name than try to access it through IP address or vice versa.

Comment: As I just said the first time, it should be an SQL server connection issue :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned before it could be an SQL Exception, and since you found it, here is some ide what to check:

> " A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Here is a short tip:

[7 thing you need to check](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

But it would be good to see what is the code at the end of the message.